# What is Azure storage blob IP range for white listing

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to find the IP range for Azure storage blob. I have a storage blob. I cannot white-list domain name so I am looking for IP range for this. My blob is in USWEST region.

Could someone advice?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft provides IP address ranges in bulk for Compute, SQl and Storage, however you have a choice to whitelist only those IP for USWEST region.
As of now, you can't simply whitelist IP for Azure Blob Storage.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of this list. However I am looking for specific CIDR block/subnet.

Comment: This file will be deprecated by June 30, 2020. Please start using the JSON files listed below. IP Ranges for each cloud, broken down by region and by the tagged services in that cloud are now available on MS Download: Public: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519 US Gov: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57063 Germany: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57064 China: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57062